# I am unable to retain values in a dynamically generated Autocomplete flutter widget

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, dynamic-programming

[Mock Layout for Reference][1]

I have a list of Accounts on the left widget and a Table widget that holds the transactions for the selected Account. The table consists of multiple TextFormFields & an Autocomplete widget. Whenever I click on any Account, the Model fetches the transactions and loads them in an Array. I then loop through the entire array to generate an array of Table rows containing, TextEditingControllers & the AutoComplete widget and assign them with individual controllers which are stored in an array as well. Whatever text value I put in any of these generated widgets, gets saved to the Original array without any issues.

The problem is the dynamically generated AutoComplete widgets do not retain the values on reload. Once I click another Account from the list, the dynamically generated AutoComplete loads the values entered initially.

** How do I retain textEditingController values in a AutoComplete, the way I am able to use it for TextFormFields ?**

Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4bW9.jpg

```
loadTransactionFields(int _selectedIndex, List<AccountsTransactionData> _transactions) {
int __row=0;
selectedRowIndex=-1;
tableRowList = [];
for (var element in _transactions) {
  double? _credit = (element.credit==null? 0:element.credit);
  double? _debit = (element.debit==null? 0:element.debit);
  _balance+=_credit!-_debit!;
  __row++;
  TextEditingController tec1 = TextEditingController(text: element.date);
  TextEditingController tec2 = TextEditingController(text: element.particulars);
  TextEditingController tec3 = TextEditingController(text:  element.accountIndex.toString());
  TextEditingController tec3_string = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tec4 = TextEditingController(text: element.credit.toString());
  TextEditingController tec5 = TextEditingController(text: element.debit.toString());
  TextEditingController tec6 = TextEditingController(text: _balance.toString());
  
  // IF ACCOUNT INDEX IS NOT -1,  THEN UPDATE tec3_1.text
  (element.accountIndex != -1 ? tec3_string.text = accountsListData[element.accountIndex].name.toString():tec3_string.text='');
  // IF SELECTED INDEX rowInserted flag is true, 
  // (accountsListData[_selectedIndex].rowInserted ? (__row == _transactions.length ? tec6.text = '': null):null);
  print("LOAD: " + tec3.text + ' - ' + tec3_string.text);

  textController.add([tec1, tec2, tec3, tec3_string, tec4, tec5, tec6]);
  textEditor.add(AccountsTextEditingController(selectedIndex: _selectedIndex, textEditorArr: textController));
  tableRowList.add(TableBodyRow(children: [
    TableBodyCell(flexValue: 1, child: TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none), controller: tec1, onTap: () { selectedRowIndex = element.index; notifyListeners(); }, onChanged: (val) { displayContent(_selectedIndex,'loader'); }, autofocus: (__row==_transactions.length? true: false))),
    TableBodyCell(flexValue: 3, child: TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),controller: tec2, onChanged: (val) { displayContent(_selectedIndex,'loader'); })),
    TableBodyCell(flexValue: 2, child: FieldAutocomplete(accountsListData: accountsListData, accountIndex: tec3, accountName: tec3_string)),
    TableBodyCell(flexValue: 1, alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),controller: tec4, onChanged: (val) { displayContent(_selectedIndex,'loader'); })),
    TableBodyCell(flexValue: 1, alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),controller: tec5, onChanged: (val) { displayContent(_selectedIndex,'loader'); }, onFieldSubmitted: (val) { (__row==_transactions.length? addBlankTransactionFields(_selectedIndex):null); })),
    TableBodyCell(flexValue: 1, alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),controller: tec6, readOnly: true))
  ]));
}  
// displayContent(_selectedIndex,'loader_end');
notifyListeners();
```

}

Below is the Autocomplete widget:

````
   final TextEditingController accountIndex;
  final TextEditingController accountName;
  final List<AccountsListData> accountsListData;
  
  FieldAutocomplete({ 
    Key? key,
    required this.accountIndex,
    required this.accountName,
    required this.accountsListData
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
    return Autocomplete<AccountsListData>(
      initialValue: TextEditingValue(text: accountName.text),
      displayStringForOption: (AccountsListData option) => option.name,
      optionsBuilder: (value) {
        if(value.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<AccountsListData>.empty();
        }
        return accountsListData.where((AccountsListData element) => element.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.text)).toList();
      },
      onSelected: (val) {
        accountIndex.text = val.index.toString();
        // displayContent(_selectedIndex,'load_select');
      },
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: in ur FieldAutocomplete, pass a function(String?). string or any value u want to be saved. then on TextFormField onChange call that passed fucntion and whenever you type something it will send that data back to where u have created that widgt